# Mouse ScrollLeft not working on IE,Firefox,Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, mouseevent

I have created mouse scrolling event.Its working perfect on Chrome but its not working on IE,Firefox,Safari.Please help me.

http://test.hybreed.co/demo2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: I tried that but not able to understand that

Answer (score 0):

Try with `DOMMouseScroll, mousewheel, wheel` it should work.

```
$('#foo').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel wheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        alert('up');
    }
    else{
        alert('down');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE EXample](http://jsfiddle.net/CvCc6/807/)

it is working with Mouse scroll in firefox.

Comment: Mr.Govinda I am not able to access my site on IE,Firefox,Safari

Comment: Please check the link

Comment: Before a moment i could access this http://test.hybreed.co/demo2/ link in Edge and firefox also

Comment: sure,I am waiting for your positive responsive

Comment: @Hybreeder yes I am able to access your site in my both browsers.

Comment: Reply Mr.Govinda if you are accessing my site.

Comment: @Hybreeder It's could be a browser cache issue as I know.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Govinda, I am able to access the site on chrome and Microsoft edge  but not able to access in IE ,Safari,Mozila